# Node js call function once on start

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have interval function that I want to run every x min from the time my service is up. If I put it on my app js file it called only after a request to my server is done ( I guess it run on app js and call the function) is this the right way to do this? If another request to my server is done will it call to my function again?

Comment: Can you provide some code example ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but I would suggest not to do it. Instead try some job scheduler. You will have better control over the task.

Comment: We need to see your code to understand what you're talking about and/or how to best accomplish it.  Always include relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like this:

```
requestHandlerFunction(req,res){
    setIntervalFunctionSetup();
}
```

Then the setInterval function will be called each time there is a request to the server so if there were 10 request then there will be 10 interval function running around.

There is multiple solutions for this but the easiest one is to call the setInterval function after the service.listen() function call.

For an example If you have a webserver like express it will look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    setInterval(function setIntervalCallback(){
        //do something every 10 sec
    }, 10000);
});
```